# SpringBoot: SQLException: Access denied for user 'XXX'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, persistence

I have found the same issue here, but it did not help to asker, and it didnt help me too. So  I try it again after three years :)

I made a Spring Boot app with MySQL database. All CRUD operations works fine, its tested by Postman. When I add Persistance.autoconfiguration.java it makes **SQLException: Access denied for user 'XXX'@'localhost'** **(using password: NO)**. User XXX is my Windows user profile.

**Persistence.configuration.java** is placed in config package, it is placed in conferencedemo2, where  are controller, repository, ect packages.

```
package com.cg.conferencedemo2.config;

import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class PersistenceConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DataSourceBuilder builder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        builder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/conference_demo?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
        System.out.println("My custom datasource hean has benn initialized and  set");
        return  builder.build();
    }
}
```

I have  tryed  to make  this sql , but with no affect.

```
CREATE USER 'XXX'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'     ---->    0 row(s) affected   
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON conference_demo.* TO 'XXX'@'localhost'   ----->0 row(s) affected
```

**application.properties**

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/conference_demo?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=password
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**Thank you for the any advice.**

Comment: You're creating a user with password, but nowhere in your `DataSource` configuration you're using that username or password. Can you explain what you're trying to do there?

Comment: Thank you very much. I made this code with some tutorial, and  you know... :)

Answer (score 1):

[If you configure `spring.datasource.*` properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.2/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.datasource.configuration) Spring will automatically inject an `DataSource` for you, you do not need the `@Bean` producer method using the builder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just remove the port:3306 in my spring.datasource.url. If you are using phpmyadmin as a database management tool.

Here's the link for the reference: [DataSource Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.2/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.datasource.configuration)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
```